# Networked application using TCP sockets - Server side: Java / Client side: Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to develop a simple application using TCP sockets.
Server is in Java and Client in JavaScript.
The idea is to have inputs taken on the client, send them to the server and feeding back to the client.
The client can type CONNECT, PUT , GET,  DELETE, or DISCONNECT and server should process accordingly as per server code provided.
The problem I am having is that I am not getting a response back from the server before I get prompted for input on the client. It looks like the client will not let me take any inputs from the server until I close the client socket. When I type DISCONNECT, whatever I have typed in, the server will spit it out right before the client shuts down.
This server/client app works when I have the client developed in Java but not in JavaScript.

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class KeyValueServer {
    private static Map<String, String> keyValueStore;
    private static Map<String, Boolean> clientConnected;

    public KeyValueServer() {
        keyValueStore = new HashMap<>();
        clientConnected = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void start(int port) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + port);

            while (true) {
                // Accept incoming client connections
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected");

                // Create a new thread for each client once connected
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(clientHandler);
                clientThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: Port " + port + " is already in use.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;
        // private String clientUsername;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Read data from the client and send responses back
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    String[] tokens = inputLine.split(" ", 2);
                    String command = tokens[0];

                    switch (command) {
                        case "CONNECT":
                            if (tokens.length < 2) {
                                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                                break;
                            }
                            if (clientConnected.containsKey(tokens[1])) {
                                System.out.println("CONNECT: ERROR");
                                out.println("CONNECT: ERROR");
                                
                                break;
                            }

                            String clientId = tokens[1];
                            clientConnected.put(clientId, true);
                            // keyValueStore.putIfAbsent(clientId, "");
                            out.println("CONNECT: OK");
                            System.out.println("CONNECT: OK");
                            out.flush(); // flush the buffer to send the message immediately
                            break;

                        case "PUT":
                            if (tokens.length < 2) {
                                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                                break;
                            }
                            System.out.println(clientConnected.toString());
                            if (clientConnected.containsValue(true)) {
                                String inputLine2;
                                inputLine2 = in.readLine();
                                keyValueStore.put(tokens[1], inputLine2);
                                System.out.println(keyValueStore.toString());
                                System.out.println("PUT: OK");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("PUT: ERROR");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "GET":
                            if (tokens.length < 2) {
                                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                                break;
                            }

                            if (clientConnected.containsValue(true)) {
                                String value = keyValueStore.getOrDefault(tokens[1], "");
                                if (value.isEmpty()) {
                                    System.out.println("GET: ERROR");
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println(value);
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("GET: ERROR");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "DELETE":
                            if (tokens.length < 2) {
                                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                                break;
                            }
                            if (clientConnected.containsValue(true)) {
                                keyValueStore.remove(tokens[1]);
                                System.out.println("DELETE: OK");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("DELETE: ERROR");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "DISCONNECT":
                            if (clientConnected.containsValue(true)) {

                                clientConnected.remove(tokens[0]);
                                keyValueStore.remove(tokens[0]);
                                clientConnected.clear();
                                System.out.println("DISCONNECT: OK");
                                out.println("DISCONNECT: OK");
                                System.exit(0);
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("DISCONNECT: OK");
                                out.println("DISCONNECT: OK");
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                            out.println("ERROR: Invalid command");
                            in.close();
                            out.close();
                            clientSocket.close();
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                    }

                }

                // Close the client socket when the client disconnects
                in.close();
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyValueServer server = new KeyValueServer();
        server.start(8080);
    }

}
```

Client:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const net = require('net');

const serverAddress = 'localhost';
const port = 8080;

const client = new net.Socket();
debugger;
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

client.connect(port, serverAddress, () => {
  console.log('Connected to server');
  rl.setPrompt('Enter message to send to server: ');
  rl.prompt();
});


rl.on('line', (input) => {
    
  if (input.trim() === 'DISCONNECT') {
    client.write(input);
    client.end();
    rl.close();
  } else {
    client.write(input);
    
    rl.prompt();
  }
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Server message Received: ${data}`);
  const serverMessage = data.toString();
  console.log('Server says: ' + serverMessage);
  rl.prompt();
});

client.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Connection closed');
  process.exit(0);
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Error connecting to server: ' + err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

On the console:

### Client

Enter message to send to server: CONNECT Juan
Enter message to send to server:

### Server

Server started on port 8080
New client connected
(I should expect a "CONNECT: OK" message)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I ended up fixing up the issue by simply adding a newline character "\n" in the client.write(input) statement like so:
client.write(input + "\n");
I know \n is a character used to represent the end of a line of text and to start a new line but I don't get why this character was not necessary to be added in the Client written in Java.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your post, the "delete" link is right next to the "edit" link you used to wreck it.

Comment: Please create an answer post to present your solution.